# How do i make a clickable application with cropped icon?

Tags: macos, icons, applescript, preview, clickable

### Current status

- I have developed an applescript application with a monitor icon.

  [image: monitor icon]

### Problem

- This monitor icon is transparent in the middle, and you can't click there.

  [image: problem]

### Question

- How do i make this clickable?

### Development Environment

- AppleScript 2.5

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this problem, I embedded a text label with 1% transparency by preview.app.

A text label with 0% transparency makes no sense in this case.

Comment: An interesting issue with an innovative fix. +1